# Recreating the diag() function

Tags: r, function

I am currently trying to duplicate the `diag()` function in R to get a better understanding. Unfortunately, my solution is only useful for symmetric matrices.

```
diagnew <- function(x){
  k <- c()
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    k[i] <- x[i,i]
  }
  return(k)
}
```

I would be grateful for any tips that allow me to generalize my function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from looping pass `min(nrow, ncol)`.

```
diagnew <- function(x){
  n <- min(nrow(x), ncol(x))
  k <- vector(class(x[1,1]), n)
  for(i in seq.int(n)){
    k[i] <- x[i,i]
  }
  k
}

mat <- matrix(1:10, 5)
diag(mat)
diagnew(mat)

identical(diag(mat), diagnew(mat))
#[1] TRUE
```